# How to make VScode debug in a specific terminal?

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code, terminal

I was using WSL while learning programming in Python at the university, but have Java installed in the Windows filesystem. Now that we switched to learning Java, VScode is trying to debug from the WSL terminal, which does not work. How can I tell VScode to run the debug on the Command Prompt? I guess something path related but I am a bit lost.

I get the following error message:

```
cmd /C "c:\Users\lukas\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.35.0\scripts\launcher.bat "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:50567 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp "C:\Users\lukas\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\bf1d90699671e44dd71540a7194feefe\redhat.java\jdt_ws\Java DD1380_9c46b501\bin" Sumsort "

Command 'cmd' not found, but there are 17 similar ones.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open integrated Terminal and click the selection box, choose `Select Default Profile`, in the popping up list box, choose **Command Prompt**, then press **Ctrl+Shift+`** to open a new integrated Terminal, it's cmd.

Debugging `.java` file is also executed in CMD window in terminal. See the following gif:

[image]